# How to change TabNine to use single quotes in the Python suggested code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tabnine

I just started using TabNine for python in VS Code.  It makes some great suggestions.  However, it always uses **double quotes** for the string constants. For me this is irksome.  All the other code in my project is using single quotes.  Is there a way to tell the AI to please use single quotes for strings?

Comment: I guess you always [run](https://pypi.org/project/black) `$ black -S .` instead of `$ black .` ?

Comment: Did you use black for formatting? [Document](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/the_black_code_style/current_style.html#strings) shows that Black prefers double quotes (" and """) over single quotes (' and ''').

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT no i don't use black.  i prefer single quotes.  If you look at PEP8, all the examples also prefer single quotes.... https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/   I think it is weird that TabNine always generates double quotes.  Perhaps I should just use Black -S and it would be a non-issue